# "aws ec2 associate-address" not working when used in UserData in conjunction with Auto Scaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip, amazon-cloudformation

I'm trying to use AWS CloudFormation to create a NAT instance via an `AutoScalingGroup`, and I'm running into a problem when trying to associate an EIP during instance creation via `LaunchConfiguration` using `UserData`.

Below is my `UserData` (snipped and edited, CloudFormation template is created via Ansible hence the Jinja2 style variables),

```
 "UserData": {
     "Fn::Base64": {
         "Fn::Join": [
             "",
             [
                 "#!/bin/bash\n",
                 "\n",
                 "# Associate EIP address\n",
                 "aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id` --allocation-id {{ nat_eip_allocation_id }} --region {{ aws_region }}\n"
             ]
         ]
     }
 }
```

What's really odd is the above code outputs the following on the instance (I pipe the output to a log file),

```
 {
     "AssociationId": "eipassoc-b33d5ad7", 
     "return": "true"
 }
```

Yet when I go into my AWS console I can't find this association anywhere, the EIP isn't allocated, and the EC2 instance doesn't have the EIP, or any public IP for that matter.

If I manually associate it, it works fine.

Am I missing something really obvious here? Is it because I have `AssociatePublicIpAddress` set to `false` in the `LaunchConfiguration`? I assumed I needed to do this as I don't want an automatically assigned IP.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like setting `AssociatePublicIpAddress` to `false` does indeed block the EIP from being associated via CLI during `UserData` execution.

Seems wasteful to grab a public IP just to replace it, but the solution is to set `AssociatePublicIpAddress` to `true`.